# How do banks calculate interst on savings account

Tags: banking, interest-rate, compound-interest

Sometimes, I see banks advertise rates on savings accounts like this:
Interest is calculated daily and compounded semi annually. Now if it is compounded semi annually , how can it be calculated daily?
If, interest is 4%, compounded semi annually, then 100$ at the end of the year will become
102^2 = 104.04.

So where does the daily calculation come into play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the interest is quoted as 4% calculated daily, and compounded semi-annually.

If you simply dropped $100 into this account on Jan 1 and did nothing else, then the only activity you would see would be a deposit of $2.00 on June 30, and a further deposit of $2.04 on Dec 31.  The only time that the "calculated daily" takes effect is when there are cash flows into or out of the account during the year.

A rate of 4% a year is the equivalent of 4/365 or 0.010959% per day.

So as cash flowed into and out of the account, each day someone would calculate how much interest the balance in the account *for that day* had earned *for that day*.  The amount of this interest would be recorded somewhere, but would not appear anywhere in the account balance.

Since the interest is compounded semi-annually, on June 30 and Dec 31 the accumulated total of this interest would be credited to the account and would then begin to accumulate interest-on-interest, i.e. "compound"

I can recall, in the dim distant days of my youth, where interest was calculated (possibly on an abacus) compounded semi-annually based on the *minimum semi-annual balance*!

Comment: Thanks...that was the missing link....it has to do with cash flowing in and out of the account .

Comment: Now, the interesting thing happens when the interest is "calculated daily, compounded semi-annually, and paid monthly". What happens in that scenario?

Answer (score 5):

The way I understand it, the daily calculation means that you accrue interest every day, enough so that if you keep the same balance in your account, it would effectively be 2% every 183 days. This would be 1.02 to the power of 1/183, which is about 0.010821% daily interest.

The accrued interest would then get applied to your account about once every month, as described in [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10796/daily-interest-calculation-combined-with-monthly-compounding-why-do-banks-do-th?rq=1).